# local web application along with freebase App

Tags: freebase, mql, freebase-acre

i was just wondering if it is possible to write queries and do processing on the result (requery and do further process if required) all this as a part of a 'freebase App' on freebase.com.
And then create a local Web application on my laptop using eclipse and make use of the above (maybe via some api, ajax, etc..) to get back the result and then do some more processing at my local server (localhost) and finally display it.. is this possible?? if yes can you plz brief...

I ask this because, as i have heard there are two ways of using freebase,

1. create and host in ACRE
2. web site/app making API calls to freebase along with MQL query as a parameter

I have some processing logic which i want to perform on the resulting query before displaying, but i dont want to put it as open source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's possible, but why not put all the logic in a single place?  If you don't want to take advantage of Acre's free hosting for open source code, just put everything in your local web app.

You can create apps which provide an API using Acre (e.g. http://genderednames.freebaseapps.com/gender_api?name=Tom) but unless it's adding value, you're introducing additional latency and adding a point of failure without getting any benefit.